# how to use single submit button for postback and redirecting to a new page based on the validations from the page

Tags: php, html, forms, button, submit

I have a page written using HTML and PHP with some input fields and a submit button. How can I use the submit button on the page to postback in case of errors after the validations are performed and use the same button to redirect to a new page when there are no errors?
I tried using header(Location: "") function to redirect to a new page but I also want the data entered in my input fields on the page to be posted on the redirected page.

Is there a way I can use 2 html forms in a single page? If yes how can it be done using single submit button.

Comment: You can use 2 html forms in a single page as long as they're not overlapping `<form></form> (form 1) <form></form> (form 2)`.  If you want to use a single button you might want to look into using jQuery to hide first button on click.  However this seems messy and I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Use Ajax for this; much simpler and no redirection involved. A "one-stop-shop".

Comment: @Fred Client side validation alone is never enough!

Comment: @Richie "Back buttons" are slowly starting to be "a thing of the past". ;)

Comment: I get you bro! Time flies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single form! I assume you're aware about a form attribute called action. `<form action="foobar.php"...`

The foobar.php will handle the validation and then you can store the user input in sessions so that you can echo them back to text fields as follows:

```
$oldvalue = (isset($_SESSION['username']))? $_SESSION['username'] : '';

<input type="text" name="username " value="$oldvalue">
```

Comment: Thank you. Would the above work for postback on the same page when there are errors? For eg I have one page called "foobar.php " where i have the action ="" so that on click on submit it loads the same page and shows errors after validation. Incase of no errors I am still landing on the same foobar.php page. So can I incase of errors  redirect to new.php page and echo the values entered on the foobar.php page ? all this using single submit button and single form ?

Comment: You will have to use the same form for everything. You simply redirect a user to a different page once the data you wanted has been submitted successfully.